# Select Node Below Specific Element By ID

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get an element that is directly below a specific ID.

For example:

```
<tr>
<td><a id="element1"/></td>
<td>Some Text</td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to get the inner text of the second `td`. Using the XPath of the 2nd `td` is not always correct in my case.

With the website I am parsing this data from; the `tr` element varies in position. The only way I figured to be able to get the correct 2nd `td` is if it is directly below the specified `id` in the `a` tag that is wrapped between the 1st `td`.

How can I get the `InnerText` of the 2nd `td` ("Some Text") based on the `id` of the element above it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the xPath way:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='element1']/ancestor::td/following-sibling::td");
```

Next `td` sibling of a `td` parent of an element that has an `id` of `element1`.